# Create SSL TCP connection with java code to send string data

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp, loadrunner

I am trying to performance test a server that uses SSL TCP socket communication. Need to send a string data to the server and validate the response back.

Is there any way to perform this with java code? I am trying to use loadrunner for performance test.

Comment: Too broad. Have a look at the JSSE Reference Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes?  That's a really broad question, so here's the broad answer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/SSL-Socket-Client-Example-SslSocketClient.html